# Angular CLI Service Worker TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, service-worker

I'm developing a progressive web application in Angular 6 (Angular CLI). 
The official service worker package doesn't meet my needs, because I need to implement custom logic for fetch requests, etc (saving data into IndexedDB and so on).

My question is:

What is the right approach to implement a service-worker with custom logic in typescript along with Angular 6 and Angular CLI?

I tried to use service-worker-webpack-plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serviceworker-webpack-plugin) along with angular-builders/custom-webpack (https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders) for extending webpack configuration, but it doesn't work. 
When I specify entry for ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin as a .ts file the dist folder is empty after build. No errors.

**/*Update*/**

After specifying --verbose flag on build I get an error:

"ERROR in ./src/sw.ts
    Module build failed (from path/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):

Error: **The AngularCompilerPlugin was not found.** The @ngtools/webpack loader requires the plugin.
        at Object.ngcLoader (path\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:27:15)"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I'm hitting the same thing.

Comment: @user3481798 Unfortunately no. I wrote all custom logic (service worker script, repository etc) in javascript instead.